# update detail table from a table in PL sql oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

there is a table loan ( loan of diff type)

```
Code  Loan Type   Amount   Deduction  Balance
111    Loan1      2000       0        2000
111    Loan2      5000       0        5000
```

There is table Deduction

```
Code   Ded_amont date
111    4000       xyz
```

I am finding a solution in oracle `(pl/sql)` that update loan table one by one
on reducing balace.

Comment: Why do you think you need a stored procedure?

Comment: i have define a cursor for loan and deduction. when i update loan table it update both row which give absurd result. it should be deducted one by one on reducing balance